# Selenium 2 - IE8 differences between RemoteWebDriver and DefaultSelenium

Tags: internet-explorer-8, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

Background: I've just upgraded to use Selenium 2 and am using the RemoteWebDriver to drive my tests.  The problem is that when the RemoteWebDriver is instantiated it launches a browser (IE8) that behaves differently to the browser that Selenium launches when I use the DefaultSelenium class to drive the tests.

The browser that the RemoteWebDriver launches does not completely load the web page for my test - it displays message 'Downloading picture about:blank...' in the status bar, thus the test cannot proceed.

My question is this:
What is the difference between the IE8 browser that DefaultSelenium launches and the one  that RemoteWebDriver launches?  Can this be configured?

Cheers.

Comment: I assume you've done this: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#internet-explorer-driver?

Comment: I include the selenium-server & selenium-remote-control artifacts as dependencies in the pom.xml file.  This brings in all of the jars I believe... although I dont have webdriver-all.jar in the dependency:tree.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into Protected Mode issues in IE. For IE using the Selenium WebDriver API (that's using RemoteWebDriver), you need to configure the browser properly first. The correct settings for IE are detailed in the Selenium [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

Also note that if you're running the tests on the same machine as IE, you can skip using the RemoteWebDriver altogether, and simply create an instance of the InternetExplorerDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the exact same issue. Selenium documentation indicates that either protected mode can be off or on as long as it is consistent across the zones. I have it set to all off.

As far as the test and the code, it works perfectly in IE9, 10, FF, Chrome but IE8 just keeps throwing the (1 item remaining) Downloading picture about:blank... message.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, you can find a bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3384) but it has been set as invalid ...
In my case if I click the page I'm loading, it'll finish downloading whatever item is missing. But this is just not possible for automated testing.

Here is a workaround :

```
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/prixgrumes/");
        } catch (TimeoutException e){
            // Do nothing (IE problem ...)
        }
```

After 10s it'll just continue without waiting the element.